# What effects do exhausted cards have?

Tags: my-little-pony-ccg

In the My Little Pony Collectible Card Game [official rulebook](http://enter-play.com/products/MLP_CCG_Rulebook_web.pdf), it says that

> While a card is *exhausted*, it can't be involved in faceoffs or help you confront Problems.

This description is a little vague. Does this only mean that the character does not contribute its power to faceoffs and problems? Or do its static abilities also stop working? Do resources on exhausted characters do anything? How about exhausted resources?

In other words, when a card is exhausted, does its text (or the text of attached resources) do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Canterlot Nights version of the [comprehensive rules](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140509173956/mylittleponyccg/images/a/ab/MLP_CCG_Comprehensive_Rules_%28v2.0%29.pdf),

> (503.5) Exhausted cards do not contribute their power to Faceoffs or to confronting problems.
>
> (702.1) Continuous abilities generate continuous modifiers, and function until the card that has them loses them or leaves the appropriate zone.

So, the abilities keep working.

Answer (score 1):

The key term here is *involve*. To resolve a faceoff or problem, characters must first be involved in it. An exausted card cannot be involved in a faceoff or problem (except if it is Stubborn) and this applies to resources too. A resource played on a exausted character will not take effect in the faceoff/problem if the character cannot be involved in the faceoff. Only the involved cards contribute to the resolution of a faceoff.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "choose the cards that will be involved". The rulebook just says that all characters at the relevant problems are involved. And you didn't cover anything besides faceoffs. It's also still unclear what happens with abilities like "Your other characters at this problem get +1" or "Your opponent's characters at this problem get -1 during the score phase" on a character or on a resource. How about reactions that don't exhaust the character?

Comment: Sorry about the usage of "choose". I meant exactly what you wrote in your comment. I'll fix that.

Comment: Now, look at the wording of the ability: "Your other characters *at this problem* get +1". This means that the card that has the ability must first be involved in the problem/faceoff for its ability to affect others. In the manual, page 2, it says "While a card is exhausted, it can’t be involved in faceoffs or help you confront Problems". So, if you cannot involve your character in the problem or faceoff it is not "at it", and its ability won't work.

Comment: That seems like a bit of a leap of logic to me. Characters have locations (at one of the problems, or home) independent of the exhausted state, so "not involed in a problem" does not necessarily imply "not at the problem".

Comment: Well, I understand that being "*at* a problem/faceoff" is not exactly the same as "*involved* in a problem/faceoff", and the rules also say that a character should be "*assigned* to a problem/faceoff". It seems that the authors allowed some vagueness in the usage of terms that describe the participation of a card in a problem/faceoff. Still, I stick with what I described above because it makes sense to me in game terms.